# Scaling Azure Container Service with private ports on containers

Tags: azure, docker

In our organization, we are currently trying out the Azure Container Service with Docker Swarm. We have developed a Web API project based on .NET Core and created containers out of it. We have exposed the web api on Container’s Private Port (3000). We want to scale this to say 15 containers on three agent nodes while still accessing the web api through one single Azure load balancer url on public port 8080.

I believe we would need an Internal Load Balancer to do this but there is no documentation around it. I have seen [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/container-service-load-balancing/) article on DC\OS but we are using Docker Swarm here. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Container Service use vanilla Docker Swarm so any load balancing solution for Swarm will work in ACS, e.g. https://botleg.com/stories/load-balancing-with-docker-swarm

Same is true for DC/OS, but in this case it is documented in "Load balance containers in an Azure Container Service cluster" - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/container-service-load-balancing/